# How to change background color of button MaterialToolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How to change color of button MaterialToolbar when it pass to state pressed?

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/webview_toolbar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_up_24" />
```

On screenshot pressed state is round figure

[image]

I tried to use `ColorStateList`, it does not work with `MaterialToolbar`. But worked with `LinearLayout`.

```xml
android:background="@drawable/selector_state_list"
```

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_toolbox_item"  android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: You want to change the background color or the ripple?

Comment: @ltp I want to change color, that shows when click on button of overflow menu

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change only the color of the icon and not remove the rounded figure (it's selectableItemBackgroundBorderless and it would be a waaay harder to get rid off it, you'll need to play with overflow attributes, take a look [here](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android), section *Overflow menu attributes*
), then you can go in your fragment/activity with:

```
mainToolbar.overflowIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.selector_state_list)
```

And your selector should contain two drawables (not color as in your file) for pressed and non-pressed states with different tint colors. Just in case, if you don't know how to generate vectors: tap on the drawable folder, new -> vector asset -> clip art.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, change the button color with a `MaterialToolbar` or (androidx and a Material theme):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_up_24"/>
```

And create a drawable file `_state.xml`, add the following code. Here there are two images which are the different required ones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"  android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24_press" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>
```

In the activity.java file, add the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.state));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.webview_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, didn't works

Comment: @Viewed I updated my answer, try this and let me if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vector drawables as navigation icons,
You can easily set the color directly into the vector.

```
<vector
 ...
 android:tint="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"> // if you are using themes then ?attr/colorControlNormal or whatever as you prefer

     <path />
</vector>
```

Read here [material app bar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#contextual-action-bar)

Or

If you are using, pngs as navigation icons,
you could use "iconTint" property as follows,

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_icon"
    app:iconTint="@color/design_default_color_error"
    android:title="@string/action_one"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

For the sake of best practices, it's better to create a style & apply that style as the toolBar style or set it directly in the ap theme as below

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApptheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="iconTint">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    .
    .
</style>
```